# ExtJS grid callback on load and reload

Tags: php, json, extjs, callback

I have an Ext Grid and want to grab the JSON "success":false/true response an execute a function for each situation. I would like to have it as callback function for every grid interaction with the JSON PHP file.

Any examples of this ?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to register callbacks to the [load](http://www.extjs.com/deploy/dev/docs/source/Store.html#event-Ext.data.Store-load) and [exception](http://www.extjs.com/deploy/dev/docs/source/Store.html#event-Ext.data.Store-exception) events of the JsonStore. Something like this:

```
 var grid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
     store: new Ext.data.JsonStore({
          [...]
          listeners: {
               load: this.onLoadSuccess.crateDelegate(this),
               exception: this.onLoadException.createDelegate(this)
          }
     }),

     onLoadSuccess: function () {
          // success
     },

     onLoadException: function () {
         // error
     },

     [...]
 }
```